# Find a bound on $\delta$ given $\epsilon=0.001$.

Tags: analysis

Consider the formal definition of a definite integral:

> For all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
>   $$|x_i-x_{i-1}|<\delta\text{ for all }i=1,...,n-1\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \left|\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(\xi_i)\Delta x_i-\int_a^bf(x)\;dx\right|<\varepsilon$$

How does one go about finding a bound for $\delta$ for a given value of $\epsilon$ and function $f(x)$? In particular, consider the problem:

[image]

**Edit**: Here is the solution-

[image]

Comment: Look at the difference fpr each interval and add them.

Answer (score 1):

First, let us note
\begin{align}
|\sin x-\sin y| \leq |x-y|
\end{align}
for all $x, y \in [0, \pi]$. If we choose $\delta = \epsilon/\pi$, then we see
\begin{align}
\left|\int^\pi_0\sin x\ dx-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sin \xi_i \Delta x_i \right|\leq \sum^{n-1}_{i=1} \int^{x_{i+1}}_{x_i}|\sin x -\sin \xi_i|\ dx \leq \frac{\epsilon}{\pi}\sum^{n-1}_{i=1} \int^{x_{i+1}}_{x_i}\ dx = \epsilon. 
\end{align}